# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry while indexing

Tags: magento2, index

When I run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It gives below result

```
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:32
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-1496275200-1498867199-1-2-2477-0' for key 'IDX_EAA51B56FF092A0DCB795D1CEF812B7B', query was: INSERT INTO `catalogrule_product` (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`action_operator`,`action_amount`,`action_stop`,`sort_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:20
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
```

How to solve

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '3-1496275200-1498867199-1-2-2477-0' for key
>   'IDX_EAA51B56FF092A0DCB795D1CEF812B7B', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalogrule_product`
>   (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`action_operator`,`action_amount`,`action_stop`,`sort_order`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Try by trunicate(empty) the table: catalogrule_product.  Please take backup before this